Error Segmentation fault when compile code with vsc
I created this code to simulate the order management of a pastry shop but when i compile the code with vsc i receive the errore:segmentation fault.
Can you help me?
I define those struct
typedef struct {
char nome[MAX_NOME];
int quantita;
} Ingrediente;

typedef struct {
char nome[MAX_NOME];
Ingrediente ingredienti[MAX_INGREDIENTI];
int num_ingredienti;
} Ricetta;

typedef struct {
char nome[MAX_NOME];
int quantita;
int scadenza;
} Lotto;

typedef struct {
char nome_ricetta[MAX_NOME];
int numero_elementi;
int tempo_arrivo;
} Ordine;

typedef struct {
Ricetta ricette[MAX_RICETTE];
int num_ricette;

Lotto lotti[MAX_LOTTI];
int num_lotti;

Ordine ordini[MAX_ORDINI];
int num_ordini;

Ordine ordini_in_attesa[MAX_ORDINI];
int num_ordini_in_attesa;

int periodicita_corriere;
int capienza_corriere;
int tempo;
} GestioneOrdini;

then i wrote three functione: one for add recipe, one for remove recipe.
void aggiungi_ricetta(GestioneOrdini *gestione, char *nome_ricetta, Ingrediente 
ingredienti[], int num_ingredienti) {
for (int i = 0; i < gestione->num_ricette; i++) {
    if (strcmp(gestione->ricette[i].nome, nome_ricetta) == 0) {
        printf("ignorato\n");
        return;
    }
}
Ricetta nuova_ricetta;
strcpy(nuova_ricetta.nome, nome_ricetta);
nuova_ricetta.num_ingredienti = num_ingredienti;
for (int j = 0; j < num_ingredienti; j++) {
    nuova_ricetta.ingredienti[j] = ingredienti[j];
}
gestione->ricette[gestione->num_ricette++] = nuova_ricetta;
printf("aggiunta\n");
}

void rimuovi_ricetta(GestioneOrdini *gestione, char *nome_ricetta) {
for (int i = 0; i < gestione->num_ordini_in_attesa; i++) {
    if (strcmp(gestione->ordini_in_attesa[i].nome_ricetta, nome_ricetta) == 0) {
        printf("ordini in sospeso\n");
        return;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < gestione->num_ricette; i++) {
    if (strcmp(gestione->ricette[i].nome, nome_ricetta) == 0) {
        gestione->ricette[i] = gestione->ricette[--gestione->num_ricette];
        printf("rimossa\n");
        return;
    }
}
printf("non presente\n");
}

Another one to replenish the warehouse:
 void rifornimento(GestioneOrdini *gestione, Ingrediente ingredienti[], int quantita[], 
 int scadenza[], int num_lotti) {
 for (int i = 0; i < num_lotti; i++) {
    Lotto nuovo_lotto;
    strcpy(nuovo_lotto.nome, ingredienti[i].nome);
    nuovo_lotto.quantita = quantita[i];
    nuovo_lotto.scadenza = scadenza[i];
    gestione->lotti[gestione->num_lotti++] = nuovo_lotto;
 }
 printf("rifornito\n");

 evadi_ordini_in_attesa(gestione);
 }

 int trova_ricetta(GestioneOrdini *gestione, char *nome_ricetta) {
 for (int i = 0; i < gestione->num_ricette; i++) {
    if (strcmp(gestione->ricette[i].nome, nome_ricetta) == 0) {
        return i;
    }
 }
 return -1;
 }

 void ordine(GestioneOrdini *gestione, char *nome_ricetta, int numero_elementi) {
 int indice_ricetta = trova_ricetta(gestione, nome_ricetta);
 
 if (indice_ricetta == -1) {
    printf("rifiutato\n");
    return;
 }

 Ordine nuovo_ordine;
 strcpy(nuovo_ordine.nome_ricetta, nome_ricetta);
 nuovo_ordine.numero_elementi = numero_elementi;
 nuovo_ordine.tempo_arrivo = gestione->tempo;

 Ricetta *ricetta = &gestione->ricette[indice_ricetta];
 int ingredienti_sufficienti = 1;

 for (int j = 0; j < ricetta->num_ingredienti; j++) {
    int richiesta_totale = ricetta->ingredienti[j].quantita * numero_elementi;
    int disponibile = 0;

    for (int l = 0; l < gestione->num_lotti; l++) {
        if (strcmp(gestione->lotti[l].nome, ricetta->ingredienti[j].nome) == 0) {
            disponibile += gestione->lotti[l].quantita;
        }
    }

    if (disponibile < richiesta_totale) {
        ingredienti_sufficienti = 0;
        break;
    }
  }

 if (ingredienti_sufficienti) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ricetta->num_ingredienti; j++) {
        int richiesta_totale = ricetta->ingredienti[j].quantita * numero_elementi;

        for (int l = 0; l < gestione->num_lotti; l++) {
            if (strcmp(gestione->lotti[l].nome, ricetta->ingredienti[j].nome) == 0) {
                if (gestione->lotti[l].quantita >= richiesta_totale) {
                    gestione->lotti[l].quantita -= richiesta_totale;
                    richiesta_totale = 0;
                } else {
                    richiesta_totale -= gestione->lotti[l].quantita;
                    gestione->lotti[l].quantita = 0;
                }
            }
            if (richiesta_totale == 0) break;
        }
    }
    gestione->ordini[gestione->num_ordini++] = nuovo_ordine;
    printf("accettato\n");
 } else {
    gestione->ordini_in_attesa[gestione->num_ordini_in_attesa++] = nuovo_ordine;
    printf("accettato\n");
 }
 }

This function manage couriers:
 void gestisci_corriere(GestioneOrdini *gestione) {
  if (gestione->tempo % gestione->periodicita_corriere == 0) {
    int capienza = gestione->capienza_corriere;
    int ordini_caricati[MAX_ORDINI];
    int num_caricati = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < gestione->num_ordini; i++) {
        Ricetta *ricetta = &gestione->ricette[trova_ricetta(gestione, gestione- 
     >ordini[i].nome_ricetta)];
        int peso_ordine = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < ricetta->num_ingredienti; j++) {
            peso_ordine += ricetta->ingredienti[j].quantita * gestione- 
     >ordini[i].numero_elementi;
        }

        if (capienza >= peso_ordine) {
            capienza -= peso_ordine;
            ordini_caricati[num_caricati++] = i;
        }
    }

    if (num_caricati > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < num_caricati; i++) {
            printf("%d %s %d\n", gestione->ordini[ordini_caricati[i]].tempo_arrivo, 
    gestione->ordini[ordini_caricati[i]].nome_ricetta, gestione- 
    >ordini[ordini_caricati[i]].numero_elementi);
        }
      } else {
        printf("camioncino vuoto\n");
     }
  }
 }

This is the main function:
int main() {
GestioneOrdini gestione = {.num_ricette=0, .num_ordini_in_attesa=0, .num_ordini=0, . 
num_lotti=0, .capienza_corriere=0, .periodicita_corriere=0, .tempo=0};
scanf("%d %d", &gestione.periodicita_corriere, &gestione.capienza_corriere);


char comando[32];
while (scanf("%s", comando) != EOF) {
    gestione.tempo++;

    if (strcmp(comando, "aggiungi_ricetta") == 0) {
        char nome_ricetta[MAX_NOME];
        scanf("%s", nome_ricetta);

        Ingrediente ingredienti[MAX_INGREDIENTI];
        int num_ingredienti = 0;
        while (scanf("%s %d", ingredienti[num_ingredienti].nome, 
    &ingredienti[num_ingredienti].quantita) == 2) {
            num_ingredienti++;
            if (getchar() == '\n') break;
        }
        printf("funzione: %s %d", nome_ricetta, num_ingredienti);
        aggiungi_ricetta(&gestione, nome_ricetta, ingredienti, num_ingredienti);
    } else if (strcmp(comando, "rimuovi_ricetta") == 0) {
        char nome_ricetta[MAX_NOME];
        scanf("%s", nome_ricetta);
        rimuovi_ricetta(&gestione, nome_ricetta);
    } else if (strcmp(comando, "rifornimento") == 0) {
        Ingrediente ingredienti[MAX_INGREDIENTI];
        int quantita[MAX_INGREDIENTI];
        int scadenza[MAX_INGREDIENTI];
        int num_lotti = 0;

        while (scanf("%s %d %d", ingredienti[num_lotti].nome, &quantita[num_lotti], 
       &scadenza[num_lotti]) == 3) {
            num_lotti++;
            if (getchar() == '\n') break;
        }

        rifornimento(&gestione, ingredienti, quantita, scadenza, num_lotti);
    } else if (strcmp(comando, "ordine") == 0) {
        char nome_ricetta[MAX_NOME];
        int numero_elementi;
        scanf("%s %d", nome_ricetta, &numero_elementi);
        ordine(&gestione, nome_ricetta, numero_elementi);
    }

    gestisci_corriere(&gestione);
}

return 0;
}


Use a debugger to catch the crash, and locate when and where in your code it happens. Examine the values of all involved variables at the time of the crash. Do they all seem valid? Also, from the information you get by using the debugger, try to isolate the problem into a nice and easy to debug/fix [mre]. If you can't solve it yourself, then show us the [mre] instead of all this (mostly, probably) unrelated code.

Other things you need when creating a [mre], is to use hard-coded "input", with known values and data, instead of reading user-input. Also remember to use "input" that is invalid, too large, too small, etc., to make sure your code handles such problems correctly.

You should test all your scanfs, as in if (scanf("%...", ...) != expected) /*error*/; where expected is the number of expected assignments. If you prefer to make your program safer from user inputs, use fgets() instead.

please post the code in a way one can copy and compile instead of re-joining multiple parts of source code...
